# change $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to change my $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] file path
as right now the path is "/var/www/html" and iwant to change it into like this "/var/www/html/WordPress/indicate1May18/"

how can i do that with .htaccess
here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /WordPress/indicate1May18/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

never worked on .htaccess before

Comment: I'd avoid doing that if possible.  What you could try is using a symlink instead: `/var/www/html` -> `/path/to/your/project/pub`.  Or you could edit your server configuration to change the document root.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change your `htaccess`, look instead either for `DocumentRoot` in the apache conf file, or if you use vhosts, you can set it in in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html